# Developer Survey results conflate age at which you learned to code with how long you've been coding

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

[image: Years Since Learning to Code graph]

The text accompanying this graph says:

> A common misconception about developers is that they've all been programming since childhood. In fact, we see a wide range of experience levels. Among professional developers, one-eighth (12.5%) learned to code less than four years ago, and an additional one-eighth (13.3%) learned to code between four and six years ago. Due to the pervasiveness of online courses and coding bootcamps, adults with little to no programming experience can now more easily transition to a career as a developer.

I would personally love to see the narrative disappear around insisting that the "best" or "all" developers have been coding since childhood...but this graph doesn't really help to dispel that narrative.

- "A common misconception about developers is that they've all been programming since childhood. In fact, we see a wide range of experience levels." This text is somewhat misleading because graph shows experience level, but not age. Someone with 20 years of experience might have learned to code when they were 40, or when they were 14, but we have no way of knowing that based on the data presented. Who knows, maybe all of the people who learned to code recently are teenagers, and all the people who learned to code 20 years ago are now in their 30s and 40s.
- "Among professional developers, one-eighth (12.5%) learned to code less than four years ago, and an additional one-eighth (13.3%) learned to code between four and six years ago." I'm confused about why this text is paired with this specific graph. The graph appears to show experience levels for *all* developers, but the analysis only talks about "professional developers". Maybe either the graph or the copy should be updated so that they match?

Comment: Off-topic: So if I'm looking the percentage where developers learned to code `2 years ago`, what is it then? `5.4%` or `6.4%`?

Comment: And why does it treat learning to code as an event, rather than a process?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for pointing this out, and sorry that it's confusing.  There are a bunch of places in the analysis/write-up where we say "among professional developers..." or "among current students...."  In these cases, we are talking about sub-groups that are just one part of the "all respondents" shown on the graph.

We're working on changes to make that more explicit; stay tuned.