# Does survey insights 2017 have a wrong graph?

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey-2017

I just read the [survey insights page](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/) ant noticed two graphs that were **exactly** the same:

[image]

[image]

This is a mistake, right? There is no way these questions could have equal results, as well as an equal amount of responses, especially since not everyone who saw the first question was asked the second.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345830/73226

Comment: My God... Mr. Spock! We're all stuck... in some kind of.... time stasis.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! I've sent this over to the folks who are in charge of the survey :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! It was indeed an error on our part. We have pushed a fix which should be live on production with our next build.